# Stop the program execution after some time interval

Tags: python

I have the following code and I want to stop the program if the condition is not true for a certain period of time. Suppose the condition (sum>99999) is false for a period of 10 seconds, then this program stops and gives present sum values. I am on Windows. Any idea how to do it in Windows.

```
for j in i:            
        sum=sum+A[j]          

    if(sum>99999):
        print("Current sum is",sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should accomplish what you're describing.

```
import time
import sys

start_time = time.time()
for j in i:            
    sum = sum + A[j]          

    if sum > 99999:
        print("Current sum is ", sum)
        start_time = time.time() # reset timer if the condition becomes true
    elif time.time() - start_time >= 10:
        print("Current sum is ", sum)
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time
import sys

start = time.time()
for j in i:
    sum += A[j]
    if sum > 99999:
        print(sum)
    elif time.time() - start > 10:
        print(sum)
        break # if you just want to exit the loop or sys.exit() if you want to exit the program
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an iteration is heavy enough to render technique proposed by other answers pretty useless. If you don't have access to break execution upon condition, [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473878-timeout-function-using-threading/) or [that](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/307871/) recipes would be helpful.

I will copy the simpler one (and the one I prefer in my code):

```
import threading
def timeout(func, args=(), kwargs={}, timeout_duration=1, default=None):
    class InterruptableThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.result = None

        def run(self):
            try:
                self.result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                self.result = default

    it = InterruptableThread()
    it.start()
    it.join(timeout_duration)
    if it.isAlive():
        return default
    else:
        return it.result
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
import time

start_time = time.time()
time_limit = 2

if (comdition):
    if((time.time() - start_time) > time_limit):
        sys.exit()
else:
    #more stuff here
```

Comment: You have both syntax errors and name errors (undefined variables).